# why I get this return value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Today I was practicing some return types, and put this code:

```
def funcion(numero):
   return numero


print(funcion)
```

And the output is

```
<function funcion at 0x7fc48554f950>
```

but the weirdest thing is that each time I try to run the code it appears other output with different digets/numbers at the end, except 0x7fc48554f950 will be 0x7f8658401950 for example.

I was wondering why this happens?
The output from python 2.7.x and 3.6.5 are different as well, which would be 
and 
awalys with the beginning and ea0.

Comment: Note that you're looking at the print of the function object itself, not the return value. (because you never called your function)

Comment: try `print(function(<aNumero>))`

Comment: So, printing the object itself will appear random combinations of words and numbers?

Comment: What where you expecting to see? If you say "a number", my next question will be: Which number?

Comment: @bl4ckch4ins Not random, but the representation of a function called "funcion" stored at a certain location in memory.

Comment: it is not random it is the address where the function is pointing (in hexadecimal format)

Comment: @Clément ... *should* you happen to use CPython. YMMV in other flavours.

Comment: @Clément it doesnt appear anything it's just gives a error of syntax

Comment: @tobias_k I see, how I can understand better about the memory information? to see how it works?

Comment: It's an implementation detail you don't need to worry about much. You're looking at how a *function object* is represented when you print it. There's no inherently right or wrong or meaningful way to represent a function object, so just take it as it is and focus on the fact that you're not calling your function instead…

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205996/discussion-on-question-by-bl4ckch4ins-why-i-get-this-return-value).

Answer (score 0):

You are printing information about the function objection instead of calling it. The right way to do so would be

```py
print(funcion())
```

but you will need to pass a value for `numero` like

```py
print(funcion(10))
```